# Swiftmail Email arriving an hour late

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am in England, and have just today moved a domain over to another server.  The only problem is, the emails seem to be arriving an hour late.

I am using SwiftMailer for PHP.  I was getting an error about the timezones:

`Warning: phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /home/nudosush/public_html/pinfo.php on line 2`

(This was just using `phpinfo();`, I would have thought that would self adjust to prevent warnings).

So Swiftmail was kicking up this error, and to prevent I placed this:

`if( ! ini_get('date.timezone') )
{
   date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
}`

..At the top of my script.  Bam! No error.

However I have had complaints that the order emails (it's an e-commerce website, using payment sense, in which the card company contacts the website via a background script to inform of a successful user transaction) are arriving an hour late.  Now, We are based in the UK, the timezone is set to UTC, and `_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"]` checks out to be the correct time.

What could be causing the problem of this delay?

Comment: email can take days to arrive. if you look at the headers of an email you will see how much time it spent on each server.

Comment: Did you check your mail server's logs to see what happens after swiftmailer hands over the email? REmember that PHP and its libraries are NOT actually delivering the email to the recipient's mailbox. They just do the equvialent of walking a letter down to the mailbox on the street corner and tossing it in. After that, it's up to the postal service to actually pick it up and deliver it.